# convert an eclipse project to Makefile based project

Tags: eclipse, makefile

I have an existing eclipse project, currently with no nature. I have written a Makefile for it, and want to use it. I have tried to do project/configure, and expected to see a "convert to Makefile project" there, but there is not suchthing. I also tried to add a builder in project/properties/builder, but there is no Makefile builder there.
I suspect I have to install some plugin what is missing, but cannot figure out which. I have tried to add several c/c++ related ones (the project is actually xslt based, not c or c++), but it seems I could not find the right one.

What should I install and/or do to convert my project to Makefile based?

update:

I have the following c++ related packages installed:

```
C/C++ Autotools support 8.8.0.201509131935  org.eclipse.cdt.autotools.feature.group Eclipse CDT
C/C++ Development Tools 8.8.0.201509131935  org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group   Eclipse CDT
  C/C++ Common GDB Support  8.8.0.201509131935  org.eclipse.cdt.gdb.feature.group   Eclipse CDT
  C/C++ Development Platform    8.8.0.201509131935  org.eclipse.cdt.platform.feature.group  Eclipse CDT
  C/C++ DSF GDB Debugger Integration    8.8.0.201509131935  org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.dsf.feature.group   Eclipse CDT
  C/C++ GNU Toolchain Build Support 8.8.0.201509131935  org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.build.feature.group Eclipse CDT
  C/C++ GNU Toolchain Debug Support 8.8.0.201509131935  org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.debug.feature.group Eclipse CDT
```

A workaround would be to run make as an external tool. But I am looking for the correct solution.

Comment: Do you have the Eclipse C/C++ support installed? There is no support for makefiles in the basic Eclipse withou this.

Comment: I have updated the question with the exact list of c++ related packages installed. Yes, I believe I have c++ support installed.